Problems of linking Ws2_32.lib using gcc
I thought that when I install gcc and mingw that crucial windows libraries are already imported with that. Apperantly not. Now how do I give the gcc linker the required libraries so that it can link the assembly of this code?
#include <Winsock2.h>
//#include <Ws2_32.lib> why can't I type it like this?
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void main(){
    WSADATA Winsockdata;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &Winsockdata);
    socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM,0);
}

I get the following error:
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd7HYF8.o:main.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd7HYF8.o:main.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `__imp_socket'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I think I saw some similar questions which say that you can use -L <pathoflibrary> but I think I don't have this library installed. Where do I install it?

How do you build your code?

@cristiFati I don't understand the question I'm not that smart. like I said I installed gcc and mingw. edited the path variable like shown in guides and use vscode editor and compile in the terminal with the gcc  command.

It's not a matter of being smart or not, but of having experience with the tools (and here I see very little). Anyway, I detailed my answer.

[MS.Learn]: comment pragma - lib seems to be MS (VStudio) specific (so GCC (and possibly other compilers) ignores it). To be more precise, compiler adds a comment in the generated (.o, .obj) file, but only the MSVC linker interprets this kind of comments and acts on them (specifying the mentioned libs). For GCC, you'd have to do it the classic way: -l command line argument ([GNU.GCC]: Options for Linking).
Check [SO]: #pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib") equivalent under Linux? for more details.
code00.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


int main()
{
    WSADATA wsData;
    int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsData);
    printf("WSAStartup returned: %d\n", res);
    WSACleanup();
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}

Output:

[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q078607979]> sopr.bat
### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###

[prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%

[prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;f:\Install\Qt\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin

[prompt]> dir /b
main00.c

[prompt]> :: Specify the library via #pragma
[prompt]> gcc main00.c -o main00.exe
C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\ccT5QUCz.o:main00.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\ccT5QUCz.o:main00.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[prompt]> :: Specify the library at command line
[prompt]> gcc main00.c -o main00.exe -lWs2_32

[prompt]> dir /b
main00.c
main00.exe

[prompt]> main00.exe
WSAStartup returned: 0

Done.


So, you can safely remove that line (well, unless you want to also compile it using VStudio, and not pass the library at command line).
P.S.: That library (and the other WinAPI related ones) should be present in the Nix toolset / emulator (MinGW, MSYS2, Cygwin, ...) installation.
In VSCode (that you mentioned in a comment), you must add the library arguments in tasks.json (compiler args list). Check [SO]: Adding a C external library in Visual Studio Code.

My Path variable already had mingw64/bin included. including the library in the command worked but I have a couple questions. First: Why do you use the -o option when compiling? gcc main.c always worked before for me instead of when im also trying to include the library in the command promt. Second: I seem to understand what the #pragma comment(...) is about but now I dont get why it doesn't work. I mean in your awnswer it doesn't work as well. I looked through the link you mentioned but I still don't get it

-o : output file name (GCC classic option). I thought it was obvious in the output. About the #pragma, I explained that it doesn't work for GCC.

ah ok now i understand everything thank you

You don't need to include "ws2_32.lib", only headers meaning files that end with ".h". For this to work you have to link your compiler to "ws2_32.lib" because "winsock2.h" needs this to function. Try this:
gcc name_of_your_program.c -l ws2_32

The "-l" tells the compiler to link to what you type next. You also dont need to write "ws2_32.lib", "ws2_32" will do.
